# date '+%p' AM/PM indicator is wrong case on Fedora 20

Tags: date, formatting, gnu-coreutils

This is rather esoteric. But I have a test which tests the string of a formatted timestamp, so it's bugging me.

`date`'s man page indicates that

```
   %p     locale's equivalent of either AM or PM; blank if not known

   %P     like %p, but lower case
```

However, on Fedora 20:

```
$ date
Mon 27 Oct 22:44:22 AEDT 2014
$ date '+%p %P'
pm pm
$ TZ=Europe/Madrid date '+%p %P'
pm pm
```

The `%p` is not uppercase as it should be.

On Ubuntu 14.04 the behaviour is correct:

```
$ date
Mon Oct 27 12:20:08 CET 2014
$ date '+%p %P'
PM pm
$ TZ=Australia/Melbourne date '+%p %P'
PM pm
```

They both have the same version (8.21). Any suggestions on where to look next?

Answer (score 0):

My colleagues managed to track it down to the language setting:

```
$ LANG=en_AU.UTF-8 date '+%p %P'
AM am
$ LANG=en_GB.UTF-8 date '+%p %P'
am am
```

Now to figure out where to file a bug report...